# Name each cell on each row from 1 to 9

Tags: javascript

[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqCzy.png)I want to make a sudoku solver and to do that I need to name each `cell` from 1 to 9 in every `row`. If you know another way to make this please tell me. Here's the code:

```
function crear (){
   var table = document.getElementById("table");

   // enter code here

   for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      var showfila = document.createElement("TR");
      showfila.setAttribute("id", "myTr" + i);
      document.getElementById("table").appendChild(showfila);

      for (var a = 1; a < 10; a++) {
         var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
         input.setAttribute("id", "myInp" + a);
         document.getElementById("myTr" + i).appendChild(input); 
         document.getElementById("myInp" + a).value=a;
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: You're declaring variables and then not re-using them in some places. e.g.`document.getElementById("table").appendChild(showfila);` could just be `table.appendChild(showfila);`

Comment: thanks! it is probably messy bc i changed it so many times :'(, less code is always better!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the "name" you are talking about for each cell is the name property and also that these cells need to be created (based on your code) so you can do something like this:

**EDIT**

The name now includes the corresponding row and column. I also added comments so that if this is not what you are looking for, you can refer to them to edit your code correctly.

```
function createTable(){
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  //Loop for rows
  for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    //Loop for columns
    for (var j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
      var cell = document.createElement("TR");
      //var i would be the row and var j would be the column
      cell.name=i+"-"+j;
      table.appendChild(cell);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i need the name of the row and of the cell separated.the first for is empty isn't that the same if its 100?

Comment: I edited my answer based on your comment. Let me know if that is what you are looking for

Comment: it isn't working, but changing id to names was very useful, i found the answer by changing some numbers to strings! thanks